# use hidden input value in php code ( value created by Jquery function )

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, get

i have a hidden input value, ths one is created by a jquery function now i want to use this value in a part of php code ( in the same page ) how can i do that please thanks you a lot

Comment: huh ?  what exactly is not working and what have you tried to fix it ???

Comment: `php` runs on the server, outputs a text-like response. Your browser receives this response, now this response is generally an html-page. Browser renders this html-page ( runs any javascript, if there is ). Now do you understand that you are asking something strange.

Comment: just not speaking good english, well, i send some value from index.php to recup.php that is works, but in index.php i have some php code just want to get a value from an input to use it in this part of code

Comment: please post your code, otherwise its very hard to help

Comment: Are you actually asking how to get a value from a terxt input with juquery?

Comment: use hidden input value in php code ( value created by Jquery function )
i have a hidden input value, ths one is created by a jquery function
now i want to use this value in a part of php code ( in the same page ) 
how can i do that please
thanks you a lot

Comment: Did you posted via ajax? Also remember for php side access form fields must have the name attribute. so that you can access the field value

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the value that you've modified with client-side JavaScript code unless you first POST the variable to PHP first.

Server-Side is unable to interact with Client-Side, unless you use AJAX. (which will effectively run server-side code for you without refreshing the page)

Comment: clearly want to transform a jquery var to a php one, in the same page

Comment: @souidi I know what you want to do, but you can't. Go read up on what "client side" is and what "server side" is, because you clearly don't understand the concept. The only way to modify a server side variable with a client side one is to post it back to the server first

Answer (score -1):

the input :

```
<input name="total_name" type="hidden" id="total_id" />
```

modification of the input value

```
$('#total_id').attr('value', total);
```

the php code ( in the same page )

```
$total_ = ( the value of total_id input )

$PBX_TOTAL =100*$total_ ;
```

Comment: This isn't possible. You'd need to POST the value back to the PHP page before you can use it within PHP. Either by a normal form post or AJAX. You cannot mix server side and client side code. The one runs exclusively on server, gets processed, sends back result, the other changes stuff only on the client, never on the server, unless you tell it to